# Unable to connect to activemq resource adapter using thorntail

Tags: thorntail

The error message:
2018-07-17 21:59:15,134 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.ra.activemq-rar"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"message-co
nsumer-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.MediationQueueMDB.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.activemq-rar]"]}

From my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>resource-adapters</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-ra</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-rar</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.4</version>
            <type>rar</type>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
```

From my yml config file:

> swarm:
>
> ## logging: TRACE
>
> deployment:
>         org.apache.activemq:activemq-rar.rar
>
> bind:
>       address: 127.0.0.1
>
> resource-adapters:
>       resource-adapters:
>         activemq-rar:
>           archive: activemq-rar.rar
>           transaction-support: LocalTransaction
>           config-properties:
>             ServerUrl:
>               value: failover:tcp://localhost:45549
>             UserName:
>               value: buddy
>             Password:
>               value: passw0rd
>             UseInboundSession:
>               value: false
>
> connection-definitions:
>       AMQConnectionFactory:
>          jndi-name: ConnectionFactory
>          class-name: org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory
>          enabled: true
>          min-pool-size: 1
>          max-pool-size: 20
>          pool-prefill: false
>          same-rm-override: false
>          use-java-context: true
>
> ```
> admin-objects:
>   REQUESTQUEUE:
>     class-name: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue
>     jndi-name: jms.queue.mediation-queue
>     use-java-context: true
>     config-properties:
>       PhysicalName: mediation-queue   ejb3:
>  default-resource-adapter-name: activemq-rar.rar
>  default-mdb-instance-pool: mdb-st**strong text**rict-max-pool   ee:
>   default-bindings:
>       jms-connection-factory: java:/ConnectionFactory   management:
> security-realms:
>   ManagementRealm:
>     in-memory-authentication:
>       users:
>         admin:
>           password: admin
> http-interface-management-interface:
>   allowed-origins: http://localhost:8080
>   security-realm: ManagementRealm
>   console-enabled: true
> ```
>
> messaging-activemq:
>       servers:
>         default:
>           active: false
>           connection-factories:
>             InVmConnectionFactory:
>               block-on-acknowledge: true
>               entries:
>               - "java:/ArtemisConnectionFactory"
>
> jca:
>       archive-validation:
>         enabled: false

I used [Wildfly-Swarm and connection to external activemq via resource adapter: WFLYCTL0412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948043/wildfly-swarm-and-connection-to-external-activemq-via-resource-adapter-wflyctl0) as a model.

Any thoughts?